# Homomorphisms and Kernel

Tags: abstract-algebra

Define a homomorphism $f : \mathbb{Z}_{12} \to \mathbb{Z}_4$ given by $f([x]_{12}) = [3x]_4$.

Calculate the kernel $\ker(f)$.

I am not really sure how to start on this problem since I have never dealt with kernel before. How would I go about starting?

Answer (score 1):

First one should verify that $f$ is indeed a homomorphism, that is, if $x$ is a multiple of $12$, then $3x$ is a multiple of $4$ (which is true), and that $f$ is compatible with the grop operation (which is also true).

The kernel is the set of elements mapped to the neutral element. So ask yourself: For which integers $x$ is $3x$ a multiple of $4$?

To show that $f$ is onto, you couls exhibit an $x$ with $f(x)=y$ for *every* element $y$ of $\mathbb Z_4$. But it suffices to find such $x$ for a generator of $\mathbb Z_4$.

There cannot be an isomorphism as tere isn't even a bijection of sets.